# How can I use Stripe to delay charging a customer until a physical item is shipped?

Tags: e-commerce, stripe-payments

I'm in the process of building an online marketplace which sells shippable goods. The site will be similar to Etsy, which will connect merchants with buyers.

I'd like to be able to charge a customer's card ONLY when an item is shipped by a merchant to avoid chargebacks and provide an Amazon-like payment experience. This will also help us avoid chargebacks and payment disputes in case a merchant is slow to ship or flakes out. In some cases, the goods will take more than 7 days to be custom manufactured and shipped out

Here's an example timeline:

- 1/1/2014 - Customer adds $75 worth of items to their cart and clicks "buy". Enters credit card info.
- 1/1/2014 - Customer's card is verified and a $75 temporary hold is placed on their card. Order is sent to merchant for fulfillment.
- 1/14/2014 - Merchant ships goods to customer and adds shipping tracking info
- 1/14/2014 - Customer's card is charged for the full amount and merchant receives $75 minus fees.

I plan to use Stripe Connect for payment processing, but am not sure how to delay capturing a payment for more than 7 days. Any thoughts? I don't want to aggregate the funds under my own account and use payouts since this will likely run afoul of money transmission laws. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: It looks like Quora has a [similar question](https://www.quora.com/Stripe-company/Does-Stripe-support-deferring-a-credit-card-charge) here , but the answers don't seem to deal with the case where a merchant ships out the item but the payment fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After further research, it seems there's no way to delay **capturing** a charge past the 7 day authorization window.

But here's one way to **delay** a charge:

1. Tokenize a credit card using the stripe.js library
2. Create a new stripe **customer** passing in the token as the "card" param

An example from the Stripe FAQ: https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later

Note that the longer you wait between tokenizing a card and actually charging it, the more likely your charge will be declined for various reasons (expired card, lack of funds, fraud, etc). This also adds a layer of complexity (and lost sales) since you'll need to ask a buyer to resubmit payment info.

I'd still like to confirm that a certain amount can be charged (like a "preauthorization"), but this lets me at least charge the card at a later date.

Comment: Hey @hberg . Did you end up just creating the client card and charging it later? Stripe told me they are working on another solution but I'm a bit surprised we can authorized only 7 days. Booking.com seems to authorize for quite a bit

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a new "customer" object and attaching the card to it using the given token. When the merchant eventually comes back to mark the order as "shipped", I create and attempt to capture a charge using the saved customer. This did lead to many failed payments as sometimes the card had expired or reached its limit by that point (often 1-2 months after purchase). Definitely plan on testing all of the possible failure modes!

Comment: @hberg what do you in case of failure? Do you notify the customer by email and give option to enter a new card details?

Comment: That depends on your application. For example. if you have a marketplace where merchants are shipping their own items, you'd want to attempt the charge *before* a shipment goes out or postage is purchased. You could also give merchants an option to contact the buyer asking for updated payment info. Again, it's up to you how to handle payment failure.

Answer (score 0):

[Celery](https://www.trycelery.com/) has built a service to help you do this with Stripe.  They are very easy to use, but note that they charge 2% per transaction.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm hoping to build something directly on top of the Stripe API. In other words, how did Celery implement this feature? Is it only using Stripe's API for charges or also using some pseudo-escrow service?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can save user token and pay later with tracking info

```
# get the credit card details submitted by the form or app
token = params[:stripeToken]

# create a Customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  card: token,
  description: 'description for payinguser@example.com',
  email: 'payinguser@example.com'
)

# charge the Customer instead of the card
Stripe::Charge.create(
    amount: 1000, # in cents
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer.id
)

# save the customer ID in your database so you can use it later
save_stripe_customer_id(user, customer.id)

# later
customer_id = get_stripe_customer_id(user)

Stripe::Charge.create(
    amount: 1500, # $15.00 this time
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example @Malygin. The problem I was trying solve (a while ago) was that I didn't want my merchants to ship out their orders without getting a payment confirmation, and sometimes the card would expire by the time the merchant was ready to ship. Just wanted to find out the "best practice" and if there was any way to pre-charge the card without running afoul of stripe terms.

Answer (score -2):

Stripe release a delay method to place a hold without charging. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later

Comment: A link to solution is a good but make sure your answer provide something useful

Comment: "capture-later" has a 7 day limit on it, which the OP is looking to go beyond. From the linked page: "When a payment is authorized, the bank guarantees the amount and holds it on the customer’s card for up to seven days, or two days for in-person payments using Terminal."

Answer (score -4):

```html
<?php

require_once('stripe-php/init.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('your stripe key'); 
$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$stripeinfo = \Stripe\Token::retrieve($token);
 
     $email = $stripeinfo->email;
   
   
   $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "source" => $token,
    "email" => $email)
);

?>
```