# Delayed transfer of payment beyond 7 day capture window?

Tags: stripe-payments

Our p2p marketplace will be selling physical items ($100 - $1000) that are small enough to be shipped through regular postal courier.

My proposed flow is to use separate charges with a capture phase. Was wondering if there was a better way to go about it.

1. Buyer purchases item. Charge is authorized, but not captured. A transfer_group is defined.
2. Seller ships item within 48 hours. Once seller inputs shipping info into system, Charge is captured, but not transferred to seller yet.
3. Our systems track the package and once it shows that it has been delivered to the buyer, the buyer has 48 hours to dispute
4. If buyer doesn't dispute and 48 hours pass, the charge is then transfered to the seller.

edit: I was able to find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999446/how-can-i-use-stripe-to-delay-charging-a-customer-until-a-physical-item-is-shipp?rq=1), but it's from 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Stripe Connect for this (or at least should be) where you (the platform) authorizes a charge from the customer. Once the seller (connected account) ships the item you capture the charge. Once the charge is capture within that 48 hour period, you don't have to worry about the 7 day limit any more as the payment would have already been processed. From there, as long as your platform Stripe account is on manual payouts, you can hold the funds for that charge in the platform account for the next 48 hours to allow the customer the time to dispute if need be, then send the funds to the seller (connected account).